# Windows 95 Platform SDK?

Tags: windows, sdk, windows-95

Does anybody know where I can get the original Windows 95 Platform SDK (or Win32 SDK)? I need it for the Windows 95 DDK (driver development kit). Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it included in the MSVC installation? Or DDK/WDK installation?

Comment: I have VC++ 6.0 installed, but the DDK setup doesn't detect it. Maybe if it is included in VC++, then do you know what I have to set as the 'InstallDir' in the registry (http://support.microsoft.com/?id=249286)? And no, it's not included in DDK.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to the Win95 DDK?  Are you actually developing something for Win9x?  Or just looking for a long lost piece of sample code?

Answer (score 2):

Here's February 2003 Platform SDK which supports Windows 9x (though I don't know if it works with Windows 95 DDK):

```
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.1.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.2.cab 
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.3.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.4.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.5.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.6.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.7.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.8.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.9.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.10.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.11.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.12.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.13.cab    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.bat    
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/extract.exe
```

(links taken from https://docs.moodle.org/dev/FebruaryPlatformSDK)

WinworldPC has beta Win95 SDKs:
https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-sdk-ddk/windows-95-ddk

There is also a "16-bit SDKs" package under "Tools and Resources" on the MSDN Subscriber downloads in case you have a subscription, but it does not seem to include the Windows 95 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think [MSDN subscriptions downloads area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx) usually has stuff like this, though Windows 95 is pretty ancient; I'm not sure you're going to be able to find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try googling "A8ACFA3DD1468C7281C4D2F152364585346E0C10". Don't know how "legal/legit" this is though. Use at your own risk.

Comment: http://www.nakido.com/A8ACFA3DD1468C7281C4D2F152364585346E0C10? I already have the DDK...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good link on installing the two (SDK and DDK) but I can't find the SDK anywhere. I looked at my old VB6 install, but it doesn't look like it's on that disk. I'll keep on looking. See this for installing the two, together:
 http://www.geoffchappell.com/viewer.htm?doc=notes/windows/archive/pdk.htm

Comment: Yes, that's the the same as I was reading here: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=249286

Comment: Not sure if the SDK was on the W95 disk.

Comment: Link to W98 PSDK: http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.2.cab

Comment: When installing (Custom) Visual C++ 6.0, one of the options is: Tools,  Win32 SDK Tools (2184K)